# How to expand a selected treeview node

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, treeview

I just coded as below to expand a selected node after a postback. But it is not working. What am I missing?

```
trvMenu.CollapseAll();
//TreeNode searchNode = trvMenu.FindNode(selectedNode.Text); // Updated
//TreeNode searchNode = trvMenu.FindNode(selectedNode.Value);
TreeNode searchNode = trvMenu.FindNode(selectedNode.ValuePath);
if (searchNode != null)
  searchNode.ExpandAll();

selectedNode.Selected = true;

//selectedNode.Selected = true;
//selectedNode.ExpandAll();
```

**Image: (Updated)**
[image]

Comment: actually it is not finding the node @ .FindNode(selectedNode.Text) however the node with the text is present at 2nd level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correct method FindNode definition is:

```
public TreeNode FindNode(
string valuePath)
```

but in your example is trvMenu.FindNode(selectedNode.Text);
Just try to put trvMenu.FindNode(**selectedNode.ValuePath**);

Comment: I see. but still the same. .FindNode is not finding with the value of the node either. Please see the udpated image in my post above. Thx.

Comment: Did you tried property ValuePath or Value? Use **ValuePath**

Comment: sorry i'd got it wrong. I've again updated the code example and image and it revealed that **ValuePath was changed** after the postback (I am finding for the reason)